# Data Extension using Salesforce Custom Object with Master-detail Relationship to Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-object, query, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I'm new to SF and SFMC.

I would like to filter my Marketing Cloud Subscribers by using a Salesforce custom object.

`Subscription__c` is the object I would like to query and has a master-detail relationship to `Contact__c` and another custom object `Event__c`.

I would like to filter my data to different lists based on the `Subscription[:event]`

What would be the best method to do this on an automated process in Marketing Cloud to import this data and use the `Subscription[:contact]` for my email lists?

Comment: How are you importing this data into marketing cloud?

Comment: Have you configured [Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [**Marketing Cloud Connect**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/) configured, I'd suggest using [**Synchronized Data Sources**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/synchronized_data_sources/interact_with_synchronized_data_sources/) to ensure the object data is updated in SFMC and then use [**Query Activities**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) in an [**Automation**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/) to build and refresh your segments.

Alternatively, you could use an Import Activity to pull SF Report data into a Salesforce Data Extension, but it sounds like you'd benefit from the flexibility of the Query Activities in the first option.